# How to solve this geometry assigment?

Tags: geometry

The three elements all have the same area (64cm2). How can I calculate the h? The result is 4cm, but I don't understand how to calculate it.

[image: Picture]

EDIT: Guys, thanks a lot for the quick help! Trust me I've spent quite some time trying to solve it but I didn't realize that I can use the triangle area formula in reverse to calculate the height of the triangle (16cm). That was most helpful.

Comment: Use a formula for the area of a triangle.  Then you can fill info in for the trapezium

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes if you edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. After a while you can try a new stackexchange handle.

Comment: @EthanBolker Got it, I apologize for the newbie mistake :)

Comment: No apology necessary. Now you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rectangle is a square: you know the side, so you know the common area $A$. Of the triangle, you know the area and one side, so you also know the height perpendicular to it. Which turns out to be the difference between the two basis of the trapezium. Finally, you have a trapezium of which you know the smaller basis, the difference between the larger basis and the smaller basis, and the area: therefore you know its height.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful but still kept me thinking until I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Try and figure out the value of ? based on the top right triangle.

[image]

Comment: @no1dea You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted to say ( but did n't) is like:

The top two (square,obtuse triangle) have same area = 64.

Bottom two (half square , right triangle) have same area =32.

Use the fact that area between parallels of same base have same area. And, area does not change if height is doubled when base is halved.

Under this assumption $h=4$ as marked.

[image]

Comment: It would have been nice to leave at least *some* work left for the OP to do ...

Comment: @Bram28 Yeah, that could have been better after hinting about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, labeling the larger base of trapezium by $b$, make up a system of two equations for areas of small and large trapeziums:
$$\begin{cases} \frac{8+b}{2}\cdot h=64 \\ \frac{8+b}{2}\cdot (8+h)=3\cdot 64 \end{cases} \stackrel{(2):(1)}{\Rightarrow} \frac{8+h}{h}=3 \Rightarrow h=4.$$